# Future sequence

Tags: dart, dart-async

In the following code I thought the `f1 > f2 > f3` would be the invocation order, but only `f1` is being invoked. How can I get the 3 functions to be invoked sequentially?

I have added the following to the `main` function and it works as expected but I want to know if there are other definitive ways of achieving the same results?

```dart
print('Starting main');
List<Future> futures=new List<Future>();
Future v1=f1();
Future v2=f2();
Future v3=f3();
futures.add(v1);
futures.add(v2);
futures.add(v3);
Future.wait(futures);
print('Leaving main');

import 'dart:async';

Duration d1 = new Duration(seconds: 5);
Duration d2 = new Duration(seconds: 10);
Duration d3 = new Duration(seconds: 15);

bool r1 = false;
bool r2 = false;
bool r3 = false;

void cb1() {
    print('Entering CB1');
    r1 = true;
    print('Leaving CB1');
}

void cb2() {
    print('Entering CB2');
    r2 = true;
    print('Leaving CB2');
}

void cb3() {
    print('Entering CB3');
    r3 = true;
    print('Leaving CB3');
}

Timer t1;
Timer t2;
Timer t3;

Future<bool> start1() {
    print('Entering start1');
    Completer<bool> r = new Completer();
    r.future.then((_) {
        while (!r1) {

        }
        print('Completing start1');
        r.complete(true);
    });

    print('Leaving start1');
    return r.future;
}

Future<bool> start2() {
    print('Entering start2');
    Completer<bool> r = new Completer();
    r.future.then((_) {
        while (!r2) {

        }
        print('Completing start2');
        r.complete(true);
    });

    print('Leaving start2');
    return r.future;
}

Future<bool> start3() {
    print('Entering start3');
    Completer<bool> r = new Completer();
    r.future.then((_) {
        while (!r3) {

        }
        print('Completing start3');
        r.complete(true);
    });

    print('Leaving start3');
    return r.future;
}

Future<bool> f1() {
    print('Entering f1');
    Completer<bool> result = new Completer();
    t1 = new Timer(d1, cb1);
    result.complete(start1());

    print('Leaving f1');
    return result.future;
}

Future<bool> f2() {
    print('Entering f2');
    Completer<bool> result = new Completer();
    t2 = new Timer(d2, cb2);
    result.complete(start2());

    print('Leaving f2');
    return result.future;
}

Future<bool> f3() {
    print('Entering f3');
    Completer<bool> result = new Completer();
    t3 = new Timer(d3, cb3);
    result.complete(start3());

    print('Leaving f3');
    return result.future;
}

void main() {
    print('Starting main');
    f1().then((_) {
        f2().then((_) {
            f3().then((_) {

            });
        });
    });
    print('Leaving main');
}
```

Comment: Your `startX` methods seem very weird. What is their purpose? Loop-waiting for a variable until it has a specific value is very bad style. You should use events of callbacks but never with an empty loop.

Comment: hi there,

it is just a test code to understand how the future mechanism works. 

i am struggling to get my head around the Future concept in dart..

i think i understand your cleaned up code mate...but will get back to you....

thanks very much buddy!

Comment: Recommended reads https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/, https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/

Comment: If you have a specific question just return to SO!

Comment: how would you write code to call an async function in synced function and wait until the async func returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should clarify why you need this. I don't really get why you want them to be executed sequentially - you should give us some more information on the concept behind it.

Please give us some more information on what you want to accomplish! The following code does somehow what I think you want:

// I did some more cleanup to the code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Duration d1 = new Duration(seconds: 5);
Duration d2 = new Duration(seconds: 10);
Duration d3 = new Duration(seconds: 15);

Future<bool> f1() {
  print('Entering f1');
  Completer<bool> r = new Completer();
  new Timer(d1, () {
    r.complete(true);
  });
  print('Leaving f1');
  return r.future;
}

Future<bool> f2() {
  print('Entering f2');
  Completer<bool> r = new Completer();
  new Timer(d2, () {
    r.complete(true);
  });
  print('Leaving f2');
  return r.future;
}

Future<bool> f3() {
  print('Entering f3');
  Completer<bool> r = new Completer();
  new Timer(d3, () {
    r.complete(true);
  });
  print('Leaving f3');
  return r.future;
}

void main() {
    print('Starting main');
    f1().then((_) {
        f2().then((_) {
            f3().then((_) {

            });
        });
    });
    print('Leaving main');
}
```

Comment: hi rob, as i mentioned in my above comment, this is just a test code to  'see' how future mechanism work. your code was helpful but i dont think i have got the concept under my belt :( still searching for an in depth  tutorial on the subject.

thanks for your help mate! very much appreciated!!

Comment: It does not matter whether you listen to a future before or after it is completed, the listener will still get the result in a later microtask.

Answer (score 2):

In start1, you return a future which is never completed. Basically, what you do is:

```dart
start1() {
  var r = new Completer();
  r.then.((_) { ... r.complete() ... });
  return r.future;
}
```

Since the only complete of `r` requires `r` to be completed, that won't happen.
That means that the `result` of `f1` will wait forever on the future returned by `start1`, and `f1().then((_) ...` will never get to the `then` callback. That's why nothing is happening.

You also have a busy-waiting loop `while (!r1) {}`. If you intend that to hang if `r1` isn't true, then it works fine. Futures are not executed concurrently in Dart. You have to return to the event loop before any future callback is called, so if `r1` is false when reaching the loop, it will stay false, because no other code will ever interrupt the loop.

If I understand what you want with `start1`, maybe try rewriting it to:

```dart
// Returns a future which completes when `r1` becomes true.
start1() {
  var r = new Completer();
  void check() {
    if (r1) {
      r.complete();
    } else {
      // We can't use scheduleMicrotask here, because an infinite microtask
      // loop would prevent the timer from firing.
      Timer.run(check);  // Check again later.
    }
  }
  check();
  return r.future;
}
```

Comment: Irn, excellent explanation and a big thank you for that! how about doing a good tutorial for absolute beginners mate? ;)